Web sites are not accessible in Windows Client machine under Windows Server 2022 AD
Here is my network:
DC - 192.168.1.10 (AD DS, DHCP, DNS)
Gateway - Cisco Meraki MX67 - 192.168.1.1
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
This is the warning I'm getting on the Windows Server 2022 server manager:
warning
If you need any more details, I can get it for you.
